# How to change the DeviceCapability of P2P-DEVICE-FOUND event in WPA?

Tags: android, wpa

Operating on wpa_cli, I call "p2p_find" and get the event of the following: P2P-DEVICE-FOUND XXXXXX dev_capab=0x25 XXXXXX. Now I want to change the dev_capab of that device. How can I do on that device to get my purpose? Here is the definition about each bitmap of DeviceCapability. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DFCaU.png)

Comment: You are not likely to get answers unless you take more time to explain your problem clearly, Please see Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.